# sidebar navigation with columns

Tags: javascript, css

https://codepen.io/rudolph-reti/pen/PoqEjYm

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="java script:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Services</a><a href="#">Clients</a><a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰ open</span>
```

```
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

In the sidebar, depending on its current size and number of links, the scrollbar appears or not. I would like to set 150 px wide columns for links in the sidebar and to make the slider appear only when there is no more place for new columns. How to do that?

Edition 10.03.2020:
I would like the links to be arranged like in the text column:

- About
- Services
- Clients
- Contact

etc.

Comment: I think here problem is solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058404/how-to-use-css3-flexbox-to-create-multi-column-layout-without-expanding-vertical

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding this to your CSS:

```
.sidenav a {
min-width: 50px;
float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.sidenav a {
float:none;
}}
```

By using media queries you can style your sidebar links only for smaller screens such as all screens below 480px.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I would like the links to be arranged like text in columns (https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_multiple_columns.asp).